# Use Vaadin TreeTable like a normal Tree

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Since Vaadin `Tree` does not support lazy loading I would like to use the `TreeTable`.
The `TreeTable` should look like a normal Tree, without headers and zebra row style.

This is what I got so far:

```
TreeTable mainTree = new TreeTable();
mainTree.setSizeFull();
mainTree.setColumnHeaderMode(ColumnHeaderMode.HIDDEN);
mainTree.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(false);
```

What else should I set and how do I get rid of the zebra pattern?

Comment: You will need to use CSS and custom style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though in Vaadin documentation it says lazy loading for `Tree` is [not supported](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-tree.html), I managed to implement the following **lazy loading** `Hierarchical` interface.

It's very **important** to store all elements in a local structure (in my case in the `HashMap` `hierarchy`), do not read elements multiple times this does not work. I think because Vaadin does not use `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.softmodeler.common.CommonPlugin;
import com.softmodeler.model.OutputNode;
import com.softmodeler.service.IViewService;
import com.vaadin.data.Container.Hierarchical;
import com.vaadin.data.Item;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem;

/**
 * @author Flavio Donzé
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class OutputNodeHierachical implements Hierarchical {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8289589835030184018L;

    /** the view service */
    private IViewService service = CommonPlugin.getService(IViewService.class);

    /** collection of all root nodes */
    private List<OutputNode> rootNodes = null;
    /** parent=>children mapping */
    private Map<OutputNode, List<OutputNode>> hierarchy = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param rootNodes collection of all root nodes
     */
    public OutputNodeHierachical(List<OutputNode> rootNodes) {
        this.rootNodes = Collections.unmodifiableList(rootNodes);

        addToHierarchy(rootNodes);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> getChildren(Object itemId) {
        try {
            List<OutputNode> children = hierarchy.get(itemId);
            if (children == null) {
                OutputNode node = (OutputNode) itemId;
                children = service.getChildren(node.getNodeId(), false);

                hierarchy.put(node, children);

                // add children to hierarchy, their children will be added on click
                addToHierarchy(children);
            }
            return children;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            VaadinUtil.handleException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * add each element to the hierarchy without their children hierarchy(child=>null)
     *
     * @param children elements to add
     */
    private void addToHierarchy(List<OutputNode> children) {
        for (OutputNode child : children) {
            hierarchy.put(child, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areChildrenAllowed(Object itemId) {
        return !((OutputNode) itemId).getChilds().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object itemId) {
        return !((OutputNode) itemId).getChilds().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object itemId) {
        String parentId = ((OutputNode) itemId).getParentId();
        for (OutputNode node : hierarchy.keySet()) {
            if (node.getNodeId().equals(parentId)) {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> rootItemIds() {
        return rootNodes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRoot(Object itemId) {
        return rootNodes.contains(itemId);
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(Object itemId) {
        return new BeanItem<OutputNode>((OutputNode) itemId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsId(Object itemId) {
        return hierarchy.containsKey(itemId);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> getItemIds() {
        return hierarchy.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return hierarchy.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setParent(Object itemId, Object newParentId) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setChildrenAllowed(Object itemId, boolean areChildrenAllowed) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Item addItem(Object itemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object addItem() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeItem(Object itemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAllItems() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType(Object propertyId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> getContainerPropertyIds() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Property<?> getContainerProperty(Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addContainerProperty(Object propertyId, Class<?> type, Object defaultValue) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeContainerProperty(Object propertyId) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Adding the container to the `Tree` like this:

```
OutputNodeHierachical dataSource = new OutputNodeHierachical(rootNodes);

Tree mainTree = new Tree();
mainTree.setSizeFull();
mainTree.setContainerDataSource(dataSource);
mainTree.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -413371711541672605L;

    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        OutputNode node = (OutputNode) event.getItemId();
        openObject(node.getObjectId());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider implenting a lazy load mechanism yourself, wherein you load the root of three. Then you add an ExpandListener which, upon called, loads the children objects and adds them to the node.

```
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        final Tree t = new Tree();
        t.addItem(new TreeNode(0));
        t.addExpandListener(new ExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void nodeExpand(ExpandEvent event) {
                TreeNode node = (TreeNode) event.getItemId();
                for (TreeNode child : node.getMyChildren()){
                    t.addItem(child);
                    t.setParent(child, node);
                }
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(t);
    }

}
```